# Show shipping rate on Cart screen in Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, shipping

How can I show the shipping rate on the cart screen? At the moment this defaults to 0.00 - I assume as we don;t know the customers location so no shipping method can be applied. Ideally I want to show the standard shipping rate based on UK and then allow the user to click and change location to apply a different shipping rate. Ideally I want to do this in the Cart screen so users can see the full total before logging in or checkout out as a guest. I want to eliminate the shipping selection page. Any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: I assume this is for the Craft Commerce plugin?

Comment: Yes. Craft Commerce.

Comment: Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not tried this so early in the checkout process, but how about adding the following to your Add To Cart forms? Replace the # with the correct value obviously.

```
<input type="hidden" name="shippingAddress[countryId]" value="#">
<input type="hidden" name="shippingMethod" value="#">
```

That way, as soon as people arrive on the Cart page a country has been added already as a shipping address, which, I think, should be enough for shipping to be calculated.

Comment: This is great, thanks Clive. I have tried a quick test and I think it will work nicely.

Comment: Glad it worked!